# Can you get a Blood Bond by feeding off another Kindred's ghoul?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

A ghoul is a human that feeds on Kindred Blood, and can have Kindred blood in their system. So it follows that another Kindred feeding from a ghoul could risk becoming blood bonded to the ghoul's reagent if they fed three times?

Are there any rules on how much blood would a Kindred need to take from a ghoul for this to be a risk and how easily would the feeding Kindred be able to detect this (if they didn't have Auspex or some other power to detect a ghoul)?

I have the 1992 Edition of Vampire the Masquerade and there's very little detail on ghouls in the book, so I'm open to sources from other editions if they have more detailed handling of this kind of thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The amount of vampiric blood in the ghoul is so diluted that it cannot create a blood bond in someone who feeds from it.  In none of the sourcebooks does it say that secondary bonds can be created in this fashion, and VTM20 specifically states it can only be made from a Kindred.

Of course, if for storytelling reasons you wanted a ghoul's sire to have potent enough blood to form a bond from anyone who feeds, or if the sire is a particularly skilled Thaumaturge who created a spell for such an occasion, who's to say this doesn't exist?

Comment: There is a 'flavour text' story in the rule book about a Kindred that tricks other Kindred by mixing his own blood with Elder blood so that when the victims drink it they are blood bonded without realizing. This suggests diluting the blood in other blood is not enough to prevent blood bonding.

Comment: A ghoul can carry more than one blood point of Kindred Blood - and so a Kindred that drained a ghoul could have ingested more than one blood point's worth of the Reagent's blood along with whatever human blood was present. Is there any source that suggests mixing Kindred blood with Mortal blood robs the Kindred blood of it's powers?

Comment: There's a lack of sources that state secondary feedings cause blood bonding.  In VtM 20 and NWoD books, it states bonding happens when feeding from the vampire.  There's a lack of direct information stating whether or not a secondary bond can occur, so really it's be up to you.  Since World of Darkness rules are a bit loosey-goosey compared to other systems, play it the way you want and make sure the players understand.

Comment: Sounds good. Just for my own clarity - you start your answer by declaring that the Vampire blood in a ghoul is too diluted to create a blood bond. Is this backed up by RAW or is this your personal GM interpretation? I have been unable to find any reference that indicated how much (or how little) blood is required for a bond and only second hand sources (i.e. flavour text) that indicate that the blood need not come directly from the Vampire, but could be, say stored in a glass or bottle.

Comment: I'll step away from the dilution bit since OWoD had a billion splat books, so it's just confusing and conflicting.  The VTM20 book has all the blood bond mechanics on pg 286.  It can only be formed by a kindred, so secondary sources do not confer blood bonds for whatever reason.  Also, it only requires a sip, so much less than a full point of blood.  VTM20 pg 269 also states "a vampire may gift [...] a dose of his vitae, allowing the mortal [...] to ingest or inject it."  So it doesn't specify how it can be stored, but does allow external storage without losing its magical properties.

Comment: Could you cite the bit from V20 that says "secondary" sources can't form the bond? In Revised it was definitely possible to create blood bonds with essentially any amount of vitae delivered via any vector (I remember the same flavor text as Kaine, regarding a pet Assamite assassin), but mechanically it's a nightmare to rule that way-- PCs will, almost inevitably, end up bonding everyone they meet with trivial effort. One of many design oversights from the edition...

Comment: There's nothing to cite in V20.  There is no mechanic in the blood bonding section that says secondary bonds can be formed.  It only states that the bonded must feed from the kindred (or be injected/imbibe it elsewise).  In Revised, there are so many conflicting rules and splatbooks and power creep that its silly to try to identify a limitation.  Oversights galore!